# SQLInsert SQLExpr not working in V11

Tags: databases, sql, jdbc

This worked fine in Mathematica 7.  Any ideas how to fix it for version 11?

```
output = "{\"Name\"->\"Bob\", \"Date\"\[Rule]\"30/9/2016\"}";

SQLInsert[conn, "Table", {"ID", "Data"}, {123, SQLExpr[output]}]
```

> ... JDBC: Incorrect string value: '\xEF\x94\xA2\"3...' for column 'Data' at row 1

**Edit**

Mathematica 11 works if `\[Rule]` is replaced with `->`  i.e.

```
output = "{\"Name\"->\"Bob\", \"Date\"->\"30/9/2016\"}";
```

This is not necessary in version 7.

What operation can replace every `\[Rule]` with `->` for use in version 11?

Comment: I think this would best be fixed when you are generating that string (which I assume you do programmatically?). Where does it come from?

Comment: when I think about it, maybe it would even be worth to give some background. As your own answer shows the problem is related to character encodings and there could be other cases which would create problems. It looks like you are storing mathematica expressions as strings. Is it important that these are in `InputForm`? Will you do any search operations on them? Otherwise you could store them as `Compress`ed strings, which would guarantee that the strings only contain ASCII characters. Otherwise you might need to ensure that both ends use the same encoding. What DB are you working with?

Comment: The DB is MySQL. I think there are only rules to replace, so the solutions should suffice.

Comment: if you have a solution that works for you there might not be any reason to dive deeper into this. My own experience is that such workarounds eventually will fail -- usually at a time where one doesn't remember the details and there is even less time to understand them... As MySQL offers the possibility to set character encodings at a column level it should be quite simple to investigate that. Have you tried whether writing/reading strings with non-ascii characters works correctly? Might be worth the effort once you try to store the first non-english `"Name"` properties...

Comment: Normally `SQLExpr` would not contain a string but an expression, e.g. `output = {"Name" -> "Bob", "Date" -> "30/9/2016"}; SQLExpr[output]`.  That works fine in Mathematica 11. However, that happens not to be the case I had to fix.

Comment: Sorry, I think I still don't understand what exactly you try to do. If you are storing strings, why do you use `SQLExpr` at all? I'm also not convinced that the current solutions will solve your problem in general. Would storing and reading something `"{\"Name\"->\"Stéphane\"}"` and `"{\"Name\"->\"Günther\"}"` work with your current solution?

Comment: Thanks Albert, I understood what you meant about non-english names and it is under consideration.  I did not write the code which writes the rules as strings.  I just wanted to add a general note that normal use of `SQLExpr` with rules as expressions works fine in version 11.

Comment: OK, if you have something that works for your use case then there is no need to get into more details. I think our discussion will hopefully be good enough as a warning to future readers that in general there might be better solutions than simply replacing certain characters if they encounter similar (character encoding related) problems using ``DatabaseLink` ``...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `StringReplace` to replace `\[Rule]` with `->`:

```
StringReplace[
  "{\"Name\"->\"Bob\", \"Date\"\[Rule]\"30/9/2016\"}", 
  "\[Rule]" -> "->"
]
```

> ```
> "{\"Name\"->\"Bob\", \"Date\"->\"30/9/2016\"}"
> ```

Answer (score 0):

To replace `\[Rule]` with `->`

```
output = "{\"Name\"->\"Bob\", \"Date\"\[Rule]\"30/9/2016\"}";

output = FromCharacterCode[ToCharacterCode[output] /. (62754 -> Sequence[45, 62])];

SQLInsert[conn, "Table", {"ID", "Data"}, {123, SQLExpr[output]}]
```